# Accessing private member from derived class

Tags: c++

This might be a trivial question. Have below code,

```
class message {
public:
    virtual void setMessage(const string& name, const int& age, const string& title) const;
    virtual void getMessage(const string& name) const;
private:
    void removeMessage(const string& name);
};

class test : public message {
public:
    using message::removeMessage;
};


int main()
{
    test t;
    t.removeMessage("_");

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to expose ***removeMessage***() as a public method from the test class. But this is giving error that,

**error C2876: 'message': not all overloads are accessible**

How to expose a private method in base class as public in derived class?

Comment: `private` implies "not accessible from a derived class".  Did you perhaps mean to make that function `protected`?

Comment: @DrewDormann - you can add that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: I think existing answers have already done a good job at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private members can never be accessed on derived classes. If your intention is to have the derived class access the members of the base class then make those protected or public.

Answer (score 4):

You cant. Private means it is only accessible in the class it is defined in, and subclasses do not meet this definition. You probably want the [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/protected-cpp?view=msvc-160) keyword.

```cpp
class message {
public:
    virtual void setMessage(const string& name, const int& age, const string& title) const;
    virtual void getMessage(const string& name) const;
protected: //use protected instead
    void removeMessage(const string& name);
};

class test : public message {
public:
    using message::removeMessage;
};


int main()
{
    test t;
    t.removeMessage("_");

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Protected can be summed up as "private, but accessible in base classes aswell".